# How to remove backstack including home page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have seen many examples but none of them providing me a way to remove the entire back stack(including the home page) while navigating to the next page.

Eg: I have a few login pages once a user successfully entered login credentials user move to the home screen, so here I want to remove all previous screen which appeared till now, How can I do that?

Currently using code:

```
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                            HomeScreen.route_name, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```

Comment: Try this `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (dialogContex) => HomePageScreen()),
              ModalRoute.withName("/HomePageScreen"));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove all the routes below the pushed route, use a RoutePredicate that always returns false (e.g. (Route route) => false).

So for your code to work as expected, remove  ModalRoute.withName('/') and give a route predicate which returns false. So it should be

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                            HomeScreen.route_name, (Route<dynamic> route)=>false);
```

For reference see the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. This code push the given route onto the navigator and then remove all the previous routes even HomeScreen.

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(),
  ),
      (route) => false,
);
```

Note: This is tested on my project. So I hope it will 100% work

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (dialogContex) => HomePageScreen()),
              ModalRoute.withName("/HomePageScreen"));
```

Answer (score 0):

or with Getx:

```
Get.offNamedUntil('home', (route) => false);
```